# React Native AsyncStorage TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...state.reduce...')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, asyncstorage

I am using AsyncStorage to try to persist my redux state in my react app, but I get this error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...state.reduce...')`.
I have looked at the other answers for similar errors but had no luck. I'm not even exactly sure what is undefined because it just says "near". I have checked the state object and it isn't empty.
Here is my main code:
App.js:

```
import Main from "./src/components/Main"
import { NativeRouter } from "react-router-native"
import { createStore } from "redux"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import reducer from "./src/reducer"
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage"
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist"
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react"
import Text from "./src/components/Text"

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer)

const store = createStore(persistedReducer)
const persistor = persistStore(store)

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NativeRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={<Text>Loading...</Text>} persistor={persistor}>
          <Main />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    </NativeRouter>
  )
}
```

Here is the code for the reducer:
reducer.js:

```
const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "NEW_NOTE": {
      console.log("state :>> ", state)
      const max = state.reduce(
        (prev, current) => {
          // if (!current) return prev
          return current.id > prev.id ? current : prev
        },
        { id: 0, body: "" }
      )
      const newNote = { id: max.id + 1, body: "" }
      return state.concat(newNote)
    }
    case "UPDATE_NOTE": {
      const newNotes = state.filter((note) => action.data.id !== note.id)
      return [action.data, ...newNotes]
    }
    case "DELETE_NOTE": {
      return state.filter((note) => action.id !== note.id)
    }
    default: {
      return state
    }
  }
}

export default reducer
```

## Edit

The persisted reducer is changing the array to an object. I suppose I will need to change my code to accommodate this. Any idea why this happens?

state object with normal reducer:

```
[{"body": "Ddtstostksoyoyyxcuj", "id": 2}, {"body": "Ftistldpufipf 
Hhxgjbv", "id": 1}]
```

state object with persisted reducer:

```
{"0": {"body": "my first note", "id": 1}, "1": {"body": "my second note", "id": 2}, "2": {"body": "my third note", "id": 3}}
```

## Fix

reducer.js

```
const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
  state = Object.values(state)
  ...
```

selectors:

```
const notes = useSelector((state) => Object.values(state).slice(0, -1))
```

I had to remove the -1th element because the persistor contains an extra property:
`{"0": {"body": "Hi", "id": 7}, "1": {"body": "", "id": 8}, "2": {"body": "", "id": 9}, "_persist": {"rehydrated": true, "version": -1}}`

Comment: Please show what the state object looks like

Comment: Your state is an object, not an array, objects don't have a `reduce` method

Comment: Why would the persister have changed it from a list to an object?

Comment: Your console log is coming from the ADD_NOTE action, right? If so, it's coming in as an object, so check the steps before it gets there. The persistor would not change the form of the data - it has to be something in your code.

Comment: The persistor does change the form of the data. See my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why TypeError?

You've got this error `TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...state.reduce...')` because `state` is not an array, it's an object

Objects don't have `reduce` method

### Why `react-persist` converts your array to an object?

In [this line](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/v6.0.0/src/persistReducer.js#L66) of `react-persist` source code you can see `let { _persist, ...rest } = state || {}`. Spreading array like that will cause it to be converted to an object.

#### Is it a bug?

Maybe, I can't find anywhere in the documentation that the state must be an object.

#### How to fix it?

Either wrap your state in an object instead of using an array directly

Or convert the object back to an array every time you want to use it